# How to construct a File from Byte Array to send the file as an attachment in Email without saving the file or file path to disk?

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-boot, email

In Java, I have a byte array which is typically a file from an external API call.

I need to convert this byte array back to a File and send this as an attachment in an E-Mail ***without creating an actual File or referring to a file path in Disk***.

I am comfortable with making external API calls and constructing email with the file attachment. Except the fact that I am creating a file which is saved to disk and then sent as an attachment over an email.

Tried the usual way of writing to a File using FileOutputStream.

```
//Convert Byte Array to File
byte[] byteArrayFileObj = someProcess();
File attachmentFile = new File("FileName.abc");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(attachmentFile);
os.write(byteArrayFileObj);
os.close();

//Attach the File as an E-Mail Attachment
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
helper.addAttachment(attachmentFile.getName(), attachmentFile);
```

I need to send an E-Mail with the File as an Attachment without the File being saved to Disk.
In my case it saves a copy of the File to disk.

Googled a lot. But left with no answers to the point. Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
final InputStreamSource fileStreamSource = new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayFileObj);
helper.addAttachment("Some-file-name", fileStreamSource);
```

Comment: @GiftsonDavid You should be passing the `InputStreamSource` not a `byte[]`. As written in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the straight forward answer. It solved my issue. Accepted your answer as well.